# Can Tumblr sites pull in content from Twitter and Instagram?

Tags: twitter, instagram, tumblr

Is it possible for a Tumblr site to automatically pull in content from Twitter and Instagram, maybe depending on how it's been tagged?

I know I could do this using PHP and the Twitter/Instagram APIs, but I don't believe Tumblr gives us that sort of access.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: How is this a programming question? You're basically asking "does Tumblr have a feature to do this" - that's not about programming, and should be addressed to tumblr support instead.

Comment: It's fringe, I admit. However Tumblr is a tool used by web developers, and a solution may be found using code, but yeah... SO might not be the best fit.

Comment: Well, after a quick look at the [Tumblr API](https://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2#posting), it seems like you could simply create a script that grabs content from Twitter/Instagram and then posts it to Tumblr via REST...

Comment: To clarify, you want to pull in content from Twitter / Instagram and post it as a Tumblr post? Or do you want to display content from Twitter / Instagram on a Tumblr Page?

Comment: @mikedidthis The former, but if that's not available, the latter. Do you have an answer in either case?

Comment: @Chuck Former - No solution, but you can use the Tumblr API, like l4mpi suggested, to post content: https://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2 You could use IFTTT to link all the things: https://ifttt.com/ Later - Tumblr provides your last 20 tweets if you link up your Twitter account: https://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/twitter and you can display them on your theme using: https://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_themes#twitter